# Antlr Lexer output

Tags: output, antlr, lexer

I'm currently using antlr to write a scanner in eclipse, the tokens are scanning in fine but i'd like to display CHARLITERAL: before each one

The current output i'm getting is

```
2 'a'
2 'b'
2 'c'
3 'R'
3 'i'
3 'n'
```

however i'd like the output to be

```
CHARLITERAL: 'a'
CHARLITERAL: 'b'
```

The line of code I think is wrong is this:

```
CHAR_LITERAL options { paraphrase = "CHARLITERAL"; }: '\''(ESC|~'\'') '\'';
```

Any help is appreciated thanks, even if it's just an idea of what to do

Answer (score 2):

ANTLR doesn't output the list of tokens by itself, and doesn't have any option `paraphrase` (at least not in ANTLR 3 or ANTLR 4). If you want to output `CHARLITERAL:` before each one, then you need to explicitly output `CHARLITERAL:` before each one.

```
CharStream input = ...;
TokenSource tokenSource = new MyLexer(input);
while (true) {
  Token token = tokenSource.nextToken();
  if (token.getType() == EOF) {
    break;
  }

  System.out.print("CHARLITERAL: ");
  System.out.println(token.getText());
}
```